Best way to convert an IEnumerable<Task<T>> to an IAsyncEnumerable<T>?
This is the best I can come up with:
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> AsAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    foreach (Task<T> task in tasks)
    {
        yield return await task;
    }
}

Is there a better/recommended way?

Wasn't there a ToAsyncEnumerable in Linq already?

There was System.Linq.Async

Oh i see you wanted also to execute/await the task. Missed that.

Out of curiosity, why do you want this conversion? Why do you have a IEnumerable<Task<T>> to begin with?

@TheodorZoulias
I would like to retrieve a lazily evaluated collection of results from a GET API. The Get method is async. So, I got the results as an IEnumerable<Task> with this code: IEnumerable<Task<Response>> responses = requests.Select(async request => await Get(request));.


Is there a better/recommended way?

Not really. Your implementation is almost as good as it gets. You could consider adding cancellation support like this:
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable<T>(
    this IEnumerable<Task<T>> source,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    foreach (Task<T> task in source)
    {
        yield return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}

But it's not really needed. If the consumer wants to cancel the enumeration, they can just exit the consuming await foreach loop with a break or return. The CancellationToken would be useful if it could affect the awaited tasks, but the creation of the tasks is delegated to the source IEnumerable<Task<T>>, which is outside of the boundaries of the ToAsyncEnumerable method. For this reason I would prefer to skip the creation of the intermediate IEnumerable<Task<T>>, and project directly the underlying IEnumerable<TSource> to an IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>:
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> SelectAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask<TResult>> selector,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(selector);
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return await selector(item, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

Usage example:
IAsyncEnumerable<Response> responses = requests
    .SelectAsync(async (request, ct) => await Get(request, ct));

await foreach (Response response in responses.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
{
    //...
}

